# How to load Polymer components from multiple hosts?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I am attempting to use Polymer components loaded onto a page from multiple hosts. This causes an error as each component includes it's own local Polymer.html from each host. See Polymer Github issue #357:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/357

As a remedy I want to point all of my components to a public Polymer.html however there is no official Polymer CDN. Is another solution possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the Polymer Web Startet kit the all the Polymer elements are added to a single [elements.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/elements/elements.html) and then [vulcanize](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize) will concatinate them into a single import.

Alternatively you could use the [Polymer Magic Server](https://gist.github.com/sjmiles/f14ec792b9766fbb04ff) but this is rather for development than for production.